# mod_wsgi display-name doesn't seem to output as expected

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using the display-name option in the WSGIDaemonProcess configuration directive to display a python application's name.  I'm a little confused though as I only see it output in htop.  When I run a command to check apache such as `ps -ylC apache2` all the processes are identifying as "apache2" and not the name I gave them in the wsgi config such as "web" and "internal".

Is it possible to have them show up by display-name or am I stuck because they're still apache processes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not on an OS that uses a BSD version/port of `ps`, the display-name won't show under ps.

Actually, shouldn't you be searching instead of `apache2` but for `web` or `internal`?

Comment: Correct. On Solaris for example where both SYSV and BSD variants exist, with SYSV being the default, you would need to use /usr/ucb/ps and not /usr/bin/ps. So, OP needs to say what platform they are using.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm using Ubuntu for this.  That explains why I didn't see the display-name.  I did at first look for web and external in ps but it displays as apache2.  Thank you both for your responses.

Comment: @ThomasHibbard Under my linux installation, when I have the `display-name` set to `foo`, and run `ps -ylC apache2` I don't see any "foo", however, doing something like `ps aux`, I can see "foo".

Comment: Great, I can now see them when I run a ``ps aux``.  I hadn't thought to try that.  Thanks again!